# Change colour of a cell in a table

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have inserted a table into my SharePoint page.

How can I change the colour of a cell within the table?

Comment: You can use CSS to change the cell color inside the CEWP.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not very techy and new to sharepoint, CEWP?

Comment: @user54610 Content Editor Web Part.  When you edit a page, you can add web parts.  One such web part is the Content Editor Web Part.  It allows you to add content and/or JavaScript/CSS to the page.

Comment: Which is your SharePoint Version?

Comment: have you achieved what you need in above question? Is below given my answer helps you?

Comment: If this sharepoint online please keep in mind you must be in the "Classic Experience" in order to use the CEWP

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML Table is something like this (i.e. the thing with the background color is the only thing in the table cell):

```
<table class="htmlTable">
    <tr>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
        <td><span class="bg" >test</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use this CSS to change the color of table cell inside CEWP:

```
.htmlTable td { height: 100%;}
.htmlTable td.bg { background-color: #f00; width: 100%; height: 100%; display:block; }
```

**To Add a Content Editor Web Part to a page & add CSS in it Please follow below mentioned link for reference**

[Content Editor Web Part and CSS Tricks](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/content-editor-web-part-and-css-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

Some basic HTML is needed to do this. After you insert your table you will need to find the **Edit Source** button to find the code view for the section of the page you are editing. Find the cell in your table and add the background color style to it.

- About Tables: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
- About Background color: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp
  (words or hex colors should work)

Here is an example table I took from my SharePoint site where I colored one of the cells with yellow. Since the cell already had the *style* tag I just included the background-color style to that cell.

```
<table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 50%; background-color: yellow;">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 50%;">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The w3schools site has some 'try it' editors that can help you figure it out before doing it again on SharePoint.

Comment: Sadly SharePoint doesn't have tools to easily let you color the cells other than doing it through code. depending on the version of SharePoint you have there are some preset table styles but that is about it.

Answer (score 0):

How to access the html of Code snippets in SharePoint:

1. View page with item (ie Table) for editing
2. Click on **PAGE** in the top banner under SharePoint
3. Select the **Edit** option. Edit Page will be enabled.
4. Place mouse in area you want to edit the html (aka cell of Table).
5. Click on **FORMAT TEXT** in the top banner under **SharePoint** (Next to **Page**)
6. Select **Edit Source** menu option. Pop Up will appear permitting one to edit the HTML.
7. Edit HTML. Press **Ok**.
8. Select **Save** from **FORMAT TEXT** menu options. (Next to Page)

Hope this helps. I just ran into this exact issue myself today. I know HTML and CSS but i do not know **SharePoint**. So these easy steps aided me in completing the simple stylings for my table cells.